# Separate multiple selected address from GetAddress Method

Tags: vba, ms-word

This is a simple question really.
But I'm having a hard time to solve it.

**Background:**

I'm trying to get email address using `.GetAddress` Method of Word.Application Object.
Now, I don't have problem if the user selects single `To` and `CC` recipients.
Problem occurs when multiple emails get selected by the user.
For example, the user selects two email address and one group list.

```
rawRecip = Application.GetAddress(, "<PR_DISPLAY_NAME>", , 1, 2, True)
Debug.Print rawRecip
```

Using above code produces:

```
Smith, John, Joe, Jane, All-HQ Group
```

Each address selected is separated by a `<comma><space>`.
The problem is `SurName` and `GivenName` are also separated by the same.
Now I need to successfully get the *display name* of the 3 address selected by the user.
`Split` function doesn't get me anywhere since I cannot find or generate a unique delimiter that would separate the 3 display name.

Is there a clean way to get what I want?

```
Smith, John
Joe, Jane
All-HQ Group
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbelievable. The answer is already in front of me.
Posting this as answer just in case someone needs it.
You just need to add another character in the `GetAddress` Method.

**Edit**:<sup>Using another space character gives the best result</sup>

```
rawRecip = Application.GetAddress(, "<PR_DISPLAY_NAME>" & " ", , 1, 2, True)
```

It will produce:

```
Smith, John , Joe, Jane , All-HQ Group
```

Then you can use `Split` function and some text manipulation to get the desired result.

```
Dim i As Integer, dName
dName = Split(rawRecip, " , ")
For i = LBound(dName) To UBound(dName)
    Debug.Print dName(i)
Next
```

And the result:

```
Smith, John
Joe, Jane
All-HQ Group
```

**<sub>Note:with extra space on the last entry</sub>**